# Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/soapuiauto1/hdap-project/tar‌​get/jacoco.exec

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco

i have am running the following with this

```
clean jacoco:prepare-agent install jacoco:report -DENVIRONMENT=localhost -X
```

> pom.xml

file i am running this pom in jenkins server,its a maven project with SoapUI Maven plugin ,SoapUIproject.xml is attached to maven to do automatic SoapUI tests i am getting the following error, i have tried all the stackoverflow answers related to this project and search through the web but still cant get rid of it:

> [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @
>   soapui-maven-plugin --- [INFO] Installing
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/soapuiauto1/hdap-project/target/soapui-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   to
>   /home/jboss/.m2/repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/soapui-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   [DEBUG] Writing tracking file
>   /home/jboss/.m2/repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/_remote.repositories
>   [INFO] Installing
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/soapuiauto1/hdap-project/pom.xml to
>   /home/jboss/.m2/repository/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/soapui-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   [DEBUG] Writing tracking file  [INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to
>   missing execution data
>   file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/soapuiauto1/hdap-project/target/jacoco.exec

Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Join notifier requires a CauseAction
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0
        com.smartbear.soapui
        soapui-maven-plugin
        0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        
            
                 5.3.0
            
        
        
            
                BADGER
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        BADGER
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                TURKEY
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        TURKEY
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                PANTHER
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        PANTHER
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                QA6
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        QA6
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                QA7
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        QA7
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                QA8
                
                    false
                    
                        ENVIRONMENT
                        QA8
                    
                
                
                
            
        
        
            
                smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository
                http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/
            
            
                vonage-m2-plugin-repository
                http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus/content/repositories/Vonage-m2/

```
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${soapui.plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
                <version>${soapui.plugin.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                       <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                       <version>3.3.0</version>
                   </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jgoodies-forms</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.vonage.asl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>unifiedServices</artifactId>
                        <version>2015.12.4-RELEASE</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>*</groupId>
                                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.11</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <settingsFile>${basedir}/src/config/soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                            <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/reports</outputFolder>
                            <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/HDAP-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <projectProperties>
                                <projectProperty>ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}</projectProperty>
                            </projectProperties>
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                    <coverage>${project.build.directory}/reports</coverage>
                        </configuration>
          </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
               <!-- <configuration>
                   <destFile>${jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                    <classDumpDir>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it/classes</classDumpDir> 
                    <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
            <output>file</output>
                </configuration> -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-agent</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                      <configuration>
                           <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile> 
                            <propertyName>jacoco.agent.itArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                           <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-out</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>

                        <goals>
                            <!--<goal>dump</goal> -->
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                            <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destFile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destFile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <executions>
        <!--
            Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven
            plugin are executed.
        -->
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.itArgLine}</argLine>

                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I do not see the word "ERROR" anywhere. Do you refer to "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/soapuiauto1/hdap-project/target/jacoco.exec"?

Comment: yes thank you i have changed the question

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly setting `-DskipITs=false` when running maven in Jenkins?

Comment: i am doing this clean jacoco:prepare-agent install jacoco:report -DENVIRONMENT=localhost -X

Comment: Try adding it please. For what I see in your `pom.xml` file the integration test phase will be skipped if `skipITs` is `true`.

Comment: Is Jacoco actually running fine in some other environment (like your own machine)? Or this is your first try and you are doing it with Jenkins?

Comment: its the first time i am doing it

Comment: I suggest you to try in your own machine first. Jacoco is indeed quite cumbersome at first. You will need to spend some hours until you get it right. If you use jenkins you will be scratching your head even harder. As a rule of thumb do things bottom up complexity-wise

Comment: just get to know in other projects its running fine only one project issue